# Calling multiple variables in another Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem when I try to use a variable created in a subroutine in another subroutine.
In the following example, I create variables *Power_Origine, Power_Destination, ...* in the Sub **part0**, I can use one of them in the Sub **part1**, but I can't use more than 1 variable in a single subroutine (**part2**).

```
Sub part0()

Power_Origine = 1
Description_Origine = 2
KnownUser_Origine = 3
Power_Destination = 1
Description_Destination = 2
KnownUser_Destination = 3


part1 (Power_Destination)
part2 (Power_Origine, Power_Destination, Description_Destination, KnownUser_Destination)
'part2 Power_Origine, Power_Destination, Description_Destination, KnownUser_Destination ' This does not work either

End Sub


Sub part1(Power_Destination As Integer)
MsgBox Power_Destination
End Sub


Sub part2(Power_Origine As Integer, Power_Destination As Integer, Description_Destination As Integer, KnownUser_Destination As Integer)
MsgBox "Hello " & Power_Destination & Description_Destination
End Sub
```

How can I call these 4 variables (*Power_Origine, Power_Destination, Description_Destination, KnownUser_Destination*) in the subroutine **part2** ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't use more than 1 variable in a single subroutine (part2)

You can. Just remove `(` and `)`. So it becomes

```
part2 Power_Origine, Power_Destination, Description_Destination, KnownUser_Destination
```

or use

```
Call part2(Power_Origine, Power_Destination, Description_Destination, KnownUser_Destination)
```

Which is the same as above. You may still get an error because you have declared `Power_Origine As Integer, Power_Destination As Integer, Description_Destination As Integer, KnownUser_Destination As Integer` in `part02` but in `part0` they are `Variants`. Declare them as `Integer` in `part0` and it will work :)

```
Sub part0()
    Dim Power_Origine As Integer
    Dim Description_Origine  As Integer
    Dim KnownUser_Origine  As Integer
    Dim Power_Destination  As Integer
    Dim Description_Destination As Integer
    Dim KnownUser_Destination  As Integer

    Power_Origine = 1
    Description_Origine = 2
    KnownUser_Origine = 3
    Power_Destination = 1
    Description_Destination = 2
    KnownUser_Destination = 3

    part1 Power_Destination
    part2 Power_Origine, Power_Destination, Description_Destination, KnownUser_Destination
End Sub

Sub part1(Power_Destination As Integer)
    MsgBox Power_Destination
End Sub

Sub part2(P_Orig As Integer, P_Dest As Integer, D_Dest As Integer, K_Dest As Integer)
    MsgBox "Hello " & P_Dest & D_Dest
End Sub
```

You may also want to read up on [Passing Variables By Reference And By Value](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you !